# Get key for min value in python dict of class objects

Tags: python, dictionary, min, dictionary-comprehension

I have a custom class (simplified) like this:

```
class SoftMatch:
    def __init__(self, time_d):       
        self.time_delta = time_d
```

and a dict with instances of this class:

```
softmatches = {"Nikon": SoftMatch(1), "Canon": SoftMatch(2), "Sony": SoftMatch(3)}
```

I need to get the key and preferrably the value for the SoftMatch object with the lowest
"self.time_delta".

Could I do this with the python "min" function or a dict comprehension or a combo of those?

Comment: Just a note, self isn't implicit in a class constructor. If you want this class to instantiate properly, you need to add the "self" argument to the \_\_init\_\_ method. `def __init__(self, time_d):`

Comment: Thanks, usually pyCharm adds "self" to __init__() so I tend to forget it when outside the editor :-). I will edit the post for readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```py
>>> min(softmatches.items(), key=lambda x: x[1].time_delta)
('Nikon', <__main__.SoftMatch at 0x7f9081b81120>)
```

Comment: Thanks, I learned something new.